# Down the River... on a Broken Boat

Tags: situation

You bought a second-hand motorboat a few years ago, but are just taking it out for the first time. You get it into the water with no problem at all- why would there be? You start off moving north at an irrelevant speed. Yet, just when you are enjoying yourself, you suddenly realize that the boat's rudder is broken, and the rudder CAN'T TURN LEFT! You see a bend in the river to the left (west) just ahead. How are you supposed to steer the boat? Or are you doomed to crash on the banks?

To people who already solved the first question:

> I'm serious about solving the first question first

> What if the BOAT cannot turn left?

Comment: Think of everything in cardinal directions, as in all 90 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last second you

> turn the rudder to the right, which causes the boat to turn left. Phew!
>  (Boats turn in the opposite direction the rudder is turned. This is most apparent on tiller-controlled rudders but also true of wheel-controlled rudders which turn the rudder in the opposite direction the wheel is turned.)

Comment: If you answer the P.S. correctly, i'll accept your answer :) (bribing)

Answer (score 2):

At the last second you

> Make three right turns, to head west.

Comment: according to @cap and something called #reallife, the boat moves in the opposite direction as the rudder

Comment: so this wouldn't really fit in the first part of the question

Comment: There are 3 questions, what is the "first question"? Are they different scenarios?

Comment: there are only two questions, the first one being the rudder not being able to turn left, and the second being the boat not being able to turn left, because the answer to the first question is rot13(Obngf ghea gur bccbfvgr qverpgvba gung lbh ghea gur ehqqre, fb vs lbh ghea gur ehqqre evtug, gur obng jvyy tb yrsg)

Comment: you answered the second question correctly tho :)

Comment: If the boat can't turn left AND the rudder can't turn left, I say grab the oars and row right 3 times.

Comment: I edited the question, happy? (Not being rude--honest!)